# Unable to call Notebook when using scala code in Databricks

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I am into a situation where I am able to successfully run the below snippet in azure Databricks from a separate CMD.

```
%run ./HSCModule
```

But running into issues when including that piece of code with other scala code which is importing  below packages and getting following error.

```scala
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream} 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import java.util{Calendar, Properties} 
import org.apache.spark.SparkException
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession 
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.util._
```

> ERROR = :168: error: ';' expected but '.' found. %run
> ./HSCModule

FYI - I have also used `dbutils.notebook.run` and still facing same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix the magic commands, like, `%run`, `%pip`, etc. with the Scala/Python code in the same cell. [Documentation says](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run-a-notebook-from-another-notebook):

> `%run` **must be in a cell by itself**, because it runs the entire notebook inline.

So you need to put this magic command into a separate cell.

Comment: Thanks for answering that Alex, so is there a way by which I can call notebook in my scala code ??

Comment: Tried something like
 Val result=dbutils.notebook.run("HSCModule",0). It's not throwing any error but also not giving back any results.

Comment: these two are different things: `%run` evaluates another notebook in the context of the current, bringing all definitions/code from it into current context so you can call functions, etc. from it.  The `dbutils.notebook.run` executes another notebook as subprocess, and definitions aren't imported. If you want to return something from that notebook, you need to call `dbutils.notebook.exit` in it, and provide data - but it's limited only to strings, plus there is a limit on the size of the string (1k if I remember correctly)